# Twilio sms with interactive replies (we're doing Startup Weekend please help!)

Tags: java, sms, twilio

Is it possible to use the Twilio API with the Java SDK to accept/parse replies to SMS messages.

Can anyone point to any documentation that might explain this. So far I have not seen anything that suggests this is possible, but it was possible with Tropo - although it wasn't always "fun".

I would normally take the time to do this research myself, but I'm in the middle of a Startup Weekend so would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

When Twilio receives an SMS it will request, either via GET or POST the URL you have configured against the number that has just received the SMS at.

You can see the process here: http://www.twilio.com/sms/api

1. A user texts your number
2. Twilio receives the text
3. Twilio makes a request to your application and your app responds.

In the request Twilio makes to your app there will be a `body` parameter in the GET or POST request. You also have some other data which gets sent - more information can be found in the Twilio documentation here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms

Once your app receives the request you just need to do any processing required and you could then even SMS the person back to confirm it's being recieved.